# Add class plus add css rule on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have problem with adding specific class plus one css rule from display none to display block using jquery on click. I have navigation menu where I want to add a background plus one triangle on click and then remove it if the user click on another navigation link.

```js
 $(".navigation").on("click", function() {
   $(".navigation").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active-bg");
   if (!$(".navigation").hasClass(".triangle")) {
     $(".triangle").css({
       "display": "none"
     });
   } else if ($(".navigation").hasClass(".triangle")) {
     $(".triangle").css({
       "display": "block"
     });
   }
 });
```

```css
.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: -22px;
}

.navigation li a {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 383px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #000;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.navigation li .triangle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navigation li .triangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 1</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 2</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 3</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is example of my code. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8nwotp0/)

Comment: Your JS is a little confusing. Your `hasClass()` is checking for `.triangle`, yet you never add that class to `.navigation`

Comment: Also `hasClass()` takes a class name, not a CSS selector. You don't need the `.` at the start.

Comment: And you have `.addClass("active-bg");` but do not have a `active-bg` class defined, did you mean to just use `active`. Might want to go back through your code and make sure you are using the right names for things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleared the most of your code, you only need to remove `.active` class from all items on click and set it to the new item. Showing a `.triangle` element also depends on `.active` class of the parent element:

```js
var $items = $('.navigation li');
$items.on('click', function(e) {
    $items.removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 22px;
  position: relative;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: -22px;
}

.navigation li a {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 383px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #000;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.navigation li .triangle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

.navigation li.active .triangle {
  display: block;
}

.navigation li .triangle:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 1</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 2</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Menu 3</a>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```